# Customer Session Not working in magento 2

Tags: magento2, customer-session

This is my code,

```
   $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
   $customerSession = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');

   if ($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
        $customerSession->getCustomerId();  // get Customer Id
        $customerSession->getCustomerGroupId();
        $customerSession->getCustomer();
        $customerSession->getCustomerData();
        $myemail=(string)$customerSession->getCustomer()->getEmail();
        echo $myemail;
```

same code I run Custom module its getting customer email , but, I paste same code other magento core module, Now if condition failed `if($customerSession->isLoggedIn())`   why? how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 19):

I am facing same problem when **Cache** enable I am not able to get customer session.But I find below solution

```
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\Session
     */
    protected $_customerSession;

    public function __construct(Template\Context $context,
            \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request,
            \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository,
            \Magento\Customer\Model\SessionFactory $customerSession
        ) 
    {
        $this->request = $request;
        $this->customerRepository = $customerRepository;
        $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function getCustomerId(){
        $customer = $this->_customerSession->create();
        var_dump($customer->getCustomer()->getId());
    }
```

Use above code in block It is working even cache is enable.

**Second Solution:**

Add **cacheable="false"** in your xml

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
     <block class="Vendor\Modulename\Block\Customer" name="customer.session.data" template="Vendor_Modulename::customertab.phtml" cacheable="false" />
 </referenceContainer>
```

Add below code in block:

```
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\Session
     */
    protected $_customerSession;

    /**
     * Construct
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context
     */
    public function __construct(Template\Context $context,
            \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request,
            \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository,
            \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
        ) 
    {
        $this->request = $request;
        $this->customerRepository = $customerRepository;
        $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function getOrderData(){
        $customerId = $this->_customerSession->getCustomerId();
        return $customerId;
    }
```

Comment: It's giving Fatal error `Fatal error: Call to undefined method Magento\Customer\Model\SessionFactory::getCustomer() `

Comment: Updated code use it

Comment: Don't use cacheable="false" in your XML as it will make the entire page not cacheable. (unless this is what you want)

Comment: Never use cachable='false' in header files. It will forbid caching for all the pages because header is included on all pages. Wrong approach

Comment: @AhsanHorani Already I have given two solution, second solution only for knowledge

Answer (score 3):

That is not the correct way to do it. Using `create` you are going to instantiate a new object instead of getting the actual session.

It is the same difference as using `getModel` instead of `getSingleton` in Magento 1.

**Option 1 (the correct option in Magento2):**

Use `__construct` injection to get `Magento\Customer\Model\Session`:

```
protected $customerSession;
...
public function __construct(
  \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
) {
   $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
}
...
public function yourMethod()
{
  if ($this->customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
  ...
  }
}
...
```

**Option 2 (working, but not suggested):**

Use `get` instead of `create`:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$customerSession = $objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
```

Comment: Can you please complete code-example of OPTION 1? I am looking for solution of :https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/177964/29175

Comment: That is another problem and you should post on that issue, not this.

Comment: does not work on most pages except the checkout and account page

Answer (score 1):

use customer helper instead

```
Magento\Customer\Helper\Session\CurrentCustomer
```

to get logged in flag, you can approach with getCustomerId

Answer (score 0):

You can try by creating an object of objectManager and **should not use objectManager directly**.

Use something like,

```
class Example extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    private $_objectManager;
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectmanager
    ){
        $this->_objectManager = $objectmanager;
    }

    public function getExample()
    {
        $customerSession = $this->_objectManager->create("Magento\Customer\Model\Session");
        if ($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
            $customerData = $customerSession->getCustomer()->getData();
            /*Your logic*/
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution.

```
<?php
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $customerSession = $objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Customer');
?>
<?php if($customerSession->customerLoggedIn()): ?>
    <span data-bind="scope: 'customer'"><span data-bind="text: customer().firstname"></span></span>
    <script type="text/x-magento-init">
      {
        "*": {
            "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
                "components": {
                    "customer": {
                        "component": "Magento_Customer/js/view/customer"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
      }
    </script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks very much!This can solve my question!

get('Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Customer');
?>
customerLoggedIn()): ?>

```
<span data-bind="scope: 'customer'"><span data-bind="text: customer().firstname"></span></span>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
  {
    "*": {
        "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
            "components": {
                "customer": {
                    "component": "Magento_Customer/js/view/customer"
                }
            }
        }
    }
  }
</script>
```