# Customer Session works differenlty with cache

Tags: magento-2.1, cache, customer-session

I got one site to fix issues and noticed one very odd issue.

Below code is work well in ***DISABLE*** cache mode but not in ***ENABLE*** mode. If I enable cache then it only works on customer-account (customer/account) section but not other parts/pages of site.

Code snippet of path:

> app/design/frontend/Company/developer/Magento_Theme/templates/html/header.phtml

```
$objectManagerlogin = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$customerSession = $objectManagerlogin->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
$baseurl = $objectManagerlogin->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface')->getStore(0)->getBaseUrl();
 if($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {

      echo "Logout";

 }else { 
      echo "Login";
}
```

PS: I am aware that Object Manager should not be used  and commands (static content, reindex, cacha clean, di compilation) ran completely.

Comment: please let me know if you have issue

Comment: You have to add this code in your block file

Comment: You cannot solve it via PHP while using FPC. Every dynamic part should be handled via KnockoutJS in Magento2.

Comment: I sorted it and will post the answer as well. thx

Answer (score -2):

You can use below way to get current customer login status,

```
public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context $appContext
    ) {
        $this->appContext = $appContext;
    }

    protected function isLoggedIn()
    {
        return $this->appContext->getValue(\Magento\Customer\Model\Context::CONTEXT_AUTH);           
    }
```

Comment: How to call this in header.phtml file? and one more thing that WHY question code behave different in enabled-cache?

Comment: $objectManagerlogin = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$customerSession = $objectManagerlogin->get('Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context')->getValue(\Magento\Customer\Model\Context::CONTEXT_AUTH);
 if($customerSession->isLoggedIn()){//your code}else{//your code} try with direct code

Comment: Direct code is not working. Before that, I created a block and called that isLoggedIn but that also created problem. Can you please update question with that included creating block and calling so that i check what i missed?