# Magento2 Check if Customer is logged in - Not working

Tags: magento2, customer, blocks, session

I have taken the reference from this [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/91897/how-to-check-if-customer-is-logged-in-or-not-in-magento-2)

Created the variable `protected $_customerSession;`

Done the injection `\Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,`

But in my Function in my block class it always returns as false

```
var_dump($this->_customerSession->isLoggedIn());
```

Then I tried checking whats Happening in `$_SESSION`

```
[_session_validator_data] => Array (
    [remote_addr] => ::1
    [http_via] => 
    )
[_session_hosts] => Array (
    [localhost] => 1
    )
[default] => Array (
    [_form_key] => k9RrgTSkjcgnJ1iZ
    )
[customer_base] => Array (
    [customer_group_id] => 0
    [customer_id] => 
    )
[checkout] =>  Array ( )
[catalog] =>  Array ( )
[reports] => Array (
    [product_index_viewed_count] => 1
    )
[message] =>  Array ( )
[review] =>  Array ( )
```

My block is extending Template class

```
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template as Template;
```

My construct function looks like this

```
public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Vendor\Module\Model\Faq $faq,
        \Vendor\Module\Helper\Data $dataHelper,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Url $customerUrl,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
        array $data = []
        ) {
            $this->faq = $faq;
            $this->_registry = $registry;
            $this->_dataHelper = $dataHelper;
            $this->_customerUrl = $customerUrl;
            $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
            parent::__construct($context, $data);
            $this->setTabTitle();
    }
```

Just to add My php file in my block is custom file in my custom module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Construct code -

```
public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Vendor\Module\Model\Faq $faq,
        \Vendor\Module\Helper\Data $dataHelper,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Url $customerUrl,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request,
        \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\SessionFactory $_customerSession,
        array $data = []
        ) {
            $this->_isScopePrivate = true;
            $this->faq = $faq;
            $this->_registry = $registry;
            $this->_dataHelper = $dataHelper;
            $this->_customerUrl = $customerUrl;
            $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
            $this->request = $request;
            $this->customerRepository = $customerRepository;
            $this->customerSession = $_customerSession;
            parent::__construct($context, $data);
            $this->setTabTitle();
    }
```

Function code -

```
$customer = $this->customerSession->create();
        var_dump($customer->isLoggedIn());
```

This is what worked for me. I will be now Removing unnecessary code.

[This](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/112306/customer-session-not-working-in-magento-2) is the answer which helped from Prashant

Comment: not working....

Comment: Hilarious - I was getting issue, to which I added answer after it was resolved. But someone down-voted it.

Answer (score 0):

**can you try this**

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
    \Vendor\Module\Model\Faq $faq,
    \Vendor\Module\Helper\Data $dataHelper,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Url $customerUrl,
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
    array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_isScopePrivate = true;
        $this->faq = $faq;
        $this->_registry = $registry;
        $this->_dataHelper = $dataHelper;
        $this->_customerUrl = $customerUrl;
        $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->setTabTitle();
}
```

Comment: Tried but not working