# Getting current customer with registry in Magento2

Tags: magento2, customer, registry

below is my block file code

```
class View extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template 
{ 
protected $_registry;
protected $_customerSession; 
protected $_customer; 
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession, 
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer $customer      
) {
    $this->_registry = $registry;
    $this->_customerSession = $customerSession; 
    $this->_customer = $customer; 
    parent::__construct($context);
}

public function getUser()
{
    if (!$this->_loadValidUser()) {
        return;
    }
    return $this->registry->registry('current_user');
}   

protected function _loadValidUser($userId = null)
{
     $userId = (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('user_id');
    try {
        $user = $this->_customer->load($userId);
        $this->registry->register('current_user', $user);            
        return $user;
    }catch (Exception $e) {
       print_r($e->getMessage());
         return false;
    }

}
```

}

What is the mistake in above construction? I am getting the error like

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to
>   Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template

Comment: Please accept the answer if it helped you so it will help others.

Comment: Did you try using customerSession instead of registry?

Comment: can we not use registry?

Comment: This can help - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/236642/magento2-check-if-customer-is-logged-in-not-working

Comment: yes, @LAW is right.

Comment: Use customerSession to get perfect output instead of registry.

Comment: how to use it? Please anyone suggest me

Comment: please check my answer and let me know if still not solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code in your block file :

```
protected $_customerSession;

public function __construct(
    ......
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\SessionFactory $customerSession,
    array $data = []
    ......
)
{
    ......
    $this->_customerSession = $customerSession->create();
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
    ......
}

public function getCustomerData() {
    if ($this->_customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
        return $this->_customerSession->getCustomerData();
    }
    return false;
}
```

and display in your phtml file :

```
$customerData = $block->getCustomerData();
echo "<pre/>";
print_r($customerData);
```

Comment: I am getting userId in param and i need to register that user instead of current logged in customer.

Comment: Sorry ? I'm not getting exactly what you want to explain.

Comment: can you explain in some more detail?

Comment: In my code i used
 $userId = (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('user_id'); to get parameter.
from the parameter i am registering customer data. parameter is customer id,

Comment: Try to use this code $this->_registry->register('current_user', $user); in _loadValidUser function.

Comment: And $this->_registry->registry('current_user'); use this code in getUser function.

Comment: I am using same only now. please check my code once

Comment: In your code , you use like this => $this->registry->register('current_user', $user); . But, You need to use this line => $this->_registry->register('current_user', $user);

Comment: Ok, I will use like that, this line is correct ?
$user = $this->_customer->load($userId);
I used customer , do we need to use customerSession?

Comment: Yes. That's correct. You just need to change that 2 line which I give you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81256/discussion-between-jafar-and-rohan-hapani).

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer $customer       
){
    $this->_registry = $registry;
    $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
    $this->_customer = $customer;
    parent::__construct($context);
}
```

after that changes please run below commands

`php bin/magento cache:flush` and php `bin/magento setup:di:compile`

Comment: hi kunj, used above code no error but i am not getting current customer data.